# Change first-line indent of \thanks note

Tags: footnotes, titles, indentation

I would like to change the first-line indent of the `\thanks` note to `1em`, but searching through `article.cls` and `latex.ltx` I cannot seem to figure out where the indent is specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \parindent1em%
  \@thefnmark.\ #1}
\makeatother
\title{Lorem ipsum\thanks{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}}
\author{Fredrik P}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output excerpt]

Comment: This is indeed strange.  According to the version in `base/latexrelease`, `\thanks` should call `\footnotetext[\the\c@footnote]`, but for some reason it is using the old definition of `\@makefntext`.

Comment: Aha, `\maketitle` contains the original definition for `\@makefntext`!

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for digging! `etoolbox` together with `\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\hb@xt@1.8em}{\hb@xt@1.0em}{}{}` seems to do the trick!